# Symbol lookup error on runtime

Tags: c++, c, node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to build a [lzham](https://code.google.com/p/lzham/) NodeJS binding, but I keep getting `symbol lookup error: [...] undefined symbol: [...]` errors whenever I try to call a function from lzham.

I've included lzham like so :

```
#define LZHAM_DEFINE_ZLIB_API
#include "lzham_static_lib.h"
```

And my `binding.gyp` file looks like this :

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "lzham",
      "sources": [
        "lzham.cc"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
        "lzham/include",
        "lzham/lzhamdecomp",
        "lzham/lzhamcomp",
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm compiling on Linux.

```
var lzham = require('./build/Release/lzham.node'),
    buffer = require('fs').readFileSync('compressed');

lzham.decompress(buffer);
```

This code calls a function defined in C++ that in turn calls `lzham_z_inflateInit2`, producing this error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /node-lzham/build/Release/lzham.node: undefined symbol: lzham_z_inflateInit2
```

Comment: Can you show the full error text?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as a sibling of `include_dirs`:

```
"libraries": [ "-llzham" ]
```

The exact library name may be different on your system, but hopefully that's close enough to get you on the right path.

Comment: `"libraries": ["-llzham"]` produces `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzham`. Putting an already compiled `liblzhamdecomp.a` in `libraries` still produces `symbol lookup error`

Comment: OK so the next step is to find where `lzham_z_inflateInit2` is defined.  For this you can use `nm` and/or `objdump -x` to look at your various `liblzham*` files.  I also suggest trying to link against the shared object library (*.so rather than *.a).

Comment: The `liblzham*.a` files were the only output of `cmake`, how can I build .so files?

Also, `lzham_z_inflateInit2` is found in `liblzhamdll.a`, but putting it in `libraries` produces an error on compilation:

`/usr/bin/ld: Release/obj.target/lzham/lzham.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against '_Z10DecompressRKN2v89ArgumentsE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
Release/obj.target/lzham/lzham.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
lzham.target.mk:112: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/lzham.node' failed`

Comment: Great, now we're getting somewhere!  So you now have most of what you need, except your library is built as a static one in CMake.  To do that you simply insert `SHARED` in your `add_library()` call in `CMakeLists.txt` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511496/create-a-shared-library-with-cmake

Comment: Now `make` produces this error :

Linking CXX shared library liblzhamdll.dylib
c++: error: /node-lzham/lzham/lzhamdll/liblzhamdll.dylib: No such file or directory
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-install_name'
lzhamdll/CMakeFiles/lzhamdll.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'lzhamdll/liblzhamdll.dylib' failed
make[2]: *** [lzhamdll/liblzhamdll.dylib] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:175: recipe for target 'lzhamdll/CMakeFiles/lzhamdll.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lzhamdll/CMakeFiles/lzhamdll.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Nevermind, it doesn't produce this error when I run `make` inside of `lzham/lzhamdll/` instead of `lzham/`. So I replaced my .a file with my .so one in `libraries`. No error on compilation, but running my node scripts produces `Error: liblzhamdll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: OK great.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737863/how-should-binding-gyp-be-written-to-build-a-node-js-addon-with-openni - you should add one more piece to the `libraries` array, like `"-Wl,-rpath XXX"` where XXX is replaced by the path to your .so file.  This is needed so that the .so can be located at runtime.  Alternatively, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=XXX` in your terminal before running `node`, which will force it to look in the XXX directory first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69132/discussion-between-morhaus-and-john-zwinck).